# Ubuntu 22.10 - Losing WIFI interface

Tags: networking, drivers, 22.10

On Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS I've been losing WIFI interface for quite some time. This is the first set of packages I needed to install to fix it:

```
linux-modules-5.19.0-40-generic_5.19.0-40.41~22.04.1_amd64.deb
wireless-regdb_2022.06.06-0ubuntu1~22.04.1_all.deb
linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-40-generic_5.19.0-40.41~22.04.1_amd64.deb
```

After doing update, adding new hardware (I guess that automatic driver installation triggers the same problematic process) or installing/updating app version - I lose the WIFI interface once again and I have to fix it by installing newest version of the packages above.

Diagnostic information: https://cryptpad.fr/code/#/2/code/view/ViYccNKlNTg4dinXqGPriNa3PZ1IP81OmPzAvsbfaiA/

Does anyone have an idea how to detect the root of the problem or how to stop the problem?